# Magento 2.3.1 Is there a way to apply discount to only 2nd product added to cart?

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, coupon, coupon-codes, price-rules

We want to achieve or to have below discount rule. Please let us know if it is possible or it can be achieved through any plugin.

There are 3 SKU's A, B, C. User added SKU A to the cart. The user will not get any discount. If the user adds SKU B to the cart then only the user will get a discount and only on SKU B. so condition is if the user adds 2 products to the cart out of a given list of SKU's then the user gets a discount only on second SKU added to cart.

Comment: Yes you can do this by using cart rules extension

Comment: Is there any stable extension? please let us know.

Comment: https://bsscommerce.com/magento-2-shopping-cart-price-rule-per-store-view-extension.html

Comment: https://magefan.com/blog/create-cart-price-rule-in-magento-2

Comment: https://firebearstudio.com/blog/mirasvit-extended-shopping-cart-rules-for-magento-2.html

Comment: It is also magento default functionality Marketing->Promotions->Cart Price Rules